# Hello how to run multiple clients in this code

Tags: python, android

Hello how to run multiple clients in this code  app = Client("my_account1")    app = Client("my_account2")   app = Client("my_account3") here is the full code
`

```
from loguru import logger  
from asyncio import sleep  
from pyrogram import Client, filters 
app = Client("my_accountr") 
 
TIME_SLEEP = 10 
spam_enabled = True  # Флаг, указывающий, включено ли отправление сообщений  
   
@app.on_message(filters.command('a', prefixes='-') & filters.me)  
async def enable_spam(_, message):  
    global spam_enabled  # Используем глобальный флаг 
    await message.delete() 
    if message.text.split()[1] == "1":  
        spam_enabled = False  # Устанавливаем флаг в False для прекращения отправки  
        logger.info("Остановка отправки сообщений")  
    elif message.text.split()[1] == "2":  # Добавляем проверку для команды "resume"  
        spam_enabled = True  # Устанавливаем флаг в True для возобновления отправки  
        logger.info("Возобновление отправки сообщений") 
    else:  
        while True:  # Бесконечный цикл  
            if not spam_enabled:  
                break  
            await app.send_message(  
                message.chat.id,  
                message.text.split('+')[1]  
            )  
            logger.info(f"Отправил сообщение в {message.chat.id}")  
            await sleep(float(TIME_SLEEP))  
   
app.run()
```

`

Hello how to run multiple clients in this code